# SQL query to create a new column on runtime

Tags: sql, oracle

we have a small requirement for which we need to compare a primary and a secondary table. The query will return results and include a extra Column "STATUS" which will tell the user whether the data from first table is present in second table row by row.
I'm not able to figure how to get the required result.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here you find  something on [ask] and how to build a [mcve] that can be useful to improve your question

Answer (score 2):

You failed to show us the structure of the two tables, so I assume there is (at least) one common column between the two tables that will allow you to join them.

```
select t1.*, t2.*,
       case 
         when t1.id is null then 'not present in TABLE_1'  
         when t2.id is null then 'not present in TABLE_2'
         else 'present in both tables'
       end as status
from table_1 t1 
  full outer join table_2 t2 on t1.some_id = t2.some_id
```

You will need to use the real column names instead of `some_id`. This also assumes that the column `some_id` will not contain `NULL` values in any of the two tables.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar: you are right, thanks (I always forget that Oracle has that limitation)